# Lustful Thoughts

Tags: dharma, moksha, spiritual

Someone enlightened me with their answer to lustful thoughts and god being antaryami observes each and every thought. These thoughts are said to be innate and with practice can be controlled to attain liberation. But, What if we take these for granted and develop horrible lustful thoughts? Wouldn't that be a sin? How can one ask for forgiveness and get liberated from this chatter? I am young, I happen to control all of my actions but thoughts sometimes seems uncontrollable. Is this normal for my age because of natural drive?
Explain in the perspective of god and how he directs his compassion or  punishment if this is wrong?

Comment: That's okay. *Lust* in the form of *sexual thoughts* is not a hurdle to liberation. **Attachment** to *sexual thoughts* or *people* is a hurdle to liberation. It just means you are a healthy human being and you aren't guided by bad pleasures of lust, rather they'll be good when required.

Comment: @User29449 :Knowing women as my (Lakshmi) direct manifestation, how can a yogi refrain from revering them? One should never hurt women, and should never even think of wronging them. (Lakshmi Tantra 27.42:71) Mahabharat Anushasan pava Chapter cxlv verse 50-51

Those men of foolish understandings who cast their wicked eyes upon the married wives of other men, become cursed with cogenetial blindness on account of that sinfulness of theirs .        ?

Comment: @Hope Sex is a core component of Yoga and Tantras, which should be regulated and used as a tool for improvement. The question is about a total give-up of sexual feelings. Unless a mental disorder, a total give-up is not possible. The goal of yoga is to regulate such. For a healthy person, such bursts of feelings are okay and healthy. Yoga does not seek to disrupt the normal functioning of the body. In higher tantra, transformation of such feelings for spirtual advancement is accepted too.

Comment: @User29449 if give up is not possible, how can I  or anyone else follow brahmacharya?

Comment: @Hope It simply means self control, not Castration.

Answer (score 1):

Bhagvad gita

Chapter 3, Verse 39
*Thus, a man's pure consciousness is covered by his eternal enemy in the form of lust, which is never satisfied and which burns like fire*.

Chapter 3, Verse 40
*The senses, the mind and the intelligence are the sitting places of this lust, which veils the real knowledge of the living entity and bewilders him.*

Chapter 3, Verse 41
*Therefore, O Arjuna, best of the Bhäratas, in the very beginning curb this **great symbol of sin [lust] by regulating the senses, and slay this destroyer of knowledge** **and self-realization.***

Let's see the effect of lust
Chapter 16 verse 21 ***There are three gates leading to the hell of self-destruction for the soul—lust, anger, and greed. Therefore, one should abandon all three.***
You can find many verses like this which

Now, let's discuss your problem, you have been indulged in lustful thoughts.
I think you might be scared of the result but read this before worrying more read this

*Bhagvad gita 18:65

> Always think of Me, be devoted to Me, worship Me, and offer obeisance
> to Me. Doing so, you will certainly come to Me. This is My pledge to
> you, for you are very dear to Me.

Next verse 18 :66

> Abandon all varieties of dharmas and simply surrender unto Me alone. ***I
> shall liberate you from all sinful reactions; do not fear.***

- 

Now let's  come to practical solution
Look at the time of too much lustful thoughts. Now, you will find that there are few times in day where you repeat those lustful thoughts like in night or a very boring afternoon. Now, after identifying that give yourself some work on that time. If the work is boring or you have no work, take a cold shower and hand wash and read books like gita, ramayan Or any thing you like.If you there in some boring class,suddenly these thoughts hit your mind,then just drink water and take few breathes and try to focous on class. I was also indulged in lust but I just give myself some work to be busy at that time of day. Also in start 2-3 days it would be hard to shift your mind to lust to few other things but just take a cold bath when you are too much trying to control yourself. Also if you have enough time try to practice yoga (my choice:anulom vveloulom pranayam) for 10 minutes in both evening and morning. And if your most often time of lust is at night on bed chant some mantra 108 times before you get sleep(I chant om namo bhagvade vasudevaya namah Or gayatri mantri again and again till I am fully tired for sleep).

Also you have one more question is it common to have lust in youthful day

Lust is common in every age like disease a person get cold and cough in any age but what matters is how fast you recover from it.

Also, if you are looking for some mantra to ask forgiveness try vishnushastranaam strotam told by bhisma to yudhishthir in mahabharat
Or shri ram asthakam(I don't know mantras for asking forgiveness from shiva or adi shakti because have not read them there are too many you can find them )

Comment: I didn't want to include opinions but your question required need many opinions to be answered. If you were only looking for scriptures for lust. I am sorry